# How to align tbody to thead after adding a scroll bar to tbody (display: block)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table and I am adding scrollbar to it's tbody using overflow.

Problem is the alignment between thead and tbody is getting disturbed. Here is the snippet.

```css
tbody {
    display: block;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table id="treeMapCages" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer" role="grid" aria-describedby="treeMapCages_info">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row">
            <th class="small text-muted text-uppercase dt-body-center sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="treeMapCages" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="
                                    
                                        
                                        
                                            
                                        
                                    
                                
                                : activate to sort column descending" style="width: 5%;" aria-sort="ascending">
                <div class="pretty p-default">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="editor-active js-select-all">
                    <div class="state">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </th>
            <th class="small text-muted text-uppercase sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="treeMapCages" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Cage Name: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 600px;"><strong>Storage Unit</strong></th>
            <th class="small text-muted text-uppercase center sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="treeMapCages" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Edit/Delete: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 10%;"><strong>Actions</strong></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="4" role="row" class="odd">
            <td class="dt-body-center sorting_1">
                <div class="pretty p-default">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedTagsToAssign" class="editor-active" value="4">
                    <div class="state">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Storage1</td>
            <td class=" center"><a href="" class="editor_edit" id="4">Edit</a> <a href="" class="editor_remove" id="4">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="5" role="row" class="even">
            <td class="dt-body-center sorting_1">
                <div class="pretty p-default">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedTagsToAssign" class="editor-active" value="5">
                    <div class="state">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Storage2</td>
            <td class=" center"><a href="" class="editor_edit" id="5">Edit</a> <a href="" class="editor_remove" id="5">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="6" role="row" class="odd">
            <td class="dt-body-center sorting_1">
                <div class="pretty p-default">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedTagsToAssign" class="editor-active" value="6">
                    <div class="state">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>RandomStorage1</td>
            <td class=" center"><a href="" class="editor_edit" id="6">Edit</a> <a href="" class="editor_remove" id="6">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="7" role="row" class="even">
            <td class="dt-body-center sorting_1">
                <div class="pretty p-default">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedTagsToAssign" class="editor-active" value="7">
                    <div class="state">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Storage3</td>
            <td class=" center"><a href="" class="editor_edit" id="7">Edit</a> <a href="" class="editor_remove" id="7">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="8" role="row" class="odd">
            <td class="dt-body-center sorting_1">
                <div class="pretty p-default">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedTagsToAssign" class="editor-active" value="8">
                    <div class="state">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>RandomStorage2</td>
            <td class=" center"><a href="" class="editor_edit" id="8">Edit</a> <a href="" class="editor_remove" id="8">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="9" role="row" class="even">
            <td class="dt-body-center sorting_1">
                <div class="pretty p-default">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedTagsToAssign" class="editor-active" value="9">
                    <div class="state">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Storage4</td>
            <td class=" center"><a href="" class="editor_edit" id="9">Edit</a> <a href="" class="editor_remove" id="9">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="10" role="row" class="odd">
            <td class="dt-body-center sorting_1">
                <div class="pretty p-default">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedTagsToAssign" class="editor-active" value="10">
                    <div class="state">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Storage5</td>
            <td class=" center"><a href="" class="editor_edit" id="10">Edit</a> <a href="" class="editor_remove" id="10">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="11" role="row" class="even">
            <td class="dt-body-center sorting_1">
                <div class="pretty p-default">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedTagsToAssign" class="editor-active" value="11">
                    <div class="state">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Storage6</td>
            <td class=" center"><a href="" class="editor_edit" id="11">Edit</a> <a href="" class="editor_remove" id="11">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="12" role="row" class="odd">
            <td class="dt-body-center sorting_1">
                <div class="pretty p-default">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedTagsToAssign" class="editor-active" value="12">
                    <div class="state">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Storage7</td>
            <td class=" center"><a href="" class="editor_edit" id="12">Edit</a> <a href="" class="editor_remove" id="12">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="13" role="row" class="even">
            <td class="dt-body-center sorting_1">
                <div class="pretty p-default">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedTagsToAssign" class="editor-active" value="13">
                    <div class="state">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Storage8</td>
            <td class=" center"><a href="" class="editor_edit" id="13">Edit</a> <a href="" class="editor_remove" id="13">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="14" role="row" class="odd">
            <td class="dt-body-center sorting_1">
                <div class="pretty p-default">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedTagsToAssign" class="editor-active" value="14">
                    <div class="state">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Storage9</td>
            <td class=" center"><a href="" class="editor_edit" id="14">Edit</a> <a href="" class="editor_remove" id="14">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="15" role="row" class="even">
            <td class="dt-body-center sorting_1">
                <div class="pretty p-default">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedTagsToAssign" class="editor-active" value="15">
                    <div class="state">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Storage10</td>
            <td class=" center"><a href="" class="editor_edit" id="15">Edit</a> <a href="" class="editor_remove" id="15">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lwes4vnm/)

Comment: use  `display: contents;` instead of `display:block;`

Comment: You can achieve the required layout using flex box without any trouble

Comment: try to use `colspan` attribute. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp) is a link from w3schools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the width from the th

```css
.table tbody {
  display: block;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.table thead,
tbody tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: left
}
```

```html
<table id="treeMapCages" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer" role="grid" aria-describedby="treeMapCages_info">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row">
            <th class="small text-muted text-uppercase dt-body-center sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="treeMapCages" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=": activate to sort column descending"  aria-sort="ascending">
                <div class="pretty p-default">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="editor-active js-select-all">
                    <div class="state">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </th>
            <th class="small text-muted text-uppercase sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="treeMapCages" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Cage Name: activate to sort column ascending" ><strong>Storage Unit</strong></th>
            <th class="small text-muted text-uppercase center sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="treeMapCages" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Edit/Delete: activate to sort column ascending" ><strong>Actions</strong></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="4" role="row" class="odd">
            <td class="dt-body-center sorting_1">
                <div class="pretty p-default">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedTagsToAssign" class="editor-active" value="4">
                    <div class="state">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Storage1</td>
            <td class=" center"><a href="" class="editor_edit" id="4">Edit</a> <a href="" class="editor_remove" id="4">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="5" role="row" class="even">
            <td class="dt-body-center sorting_1">
                <div class="pretty p-default">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedTagsToAssign" class="editor-active" value="5">
                    <div class="state">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Storage2</td>
            <td class=" center"><a href="" class="editor_edit" id="5">Edit</a> <a href="" class="editor_remove" id="5">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="6" role="row" class="odd">
            <td class="dt-body-center sorting_1">
                <div class="pretty p-default">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedTagsToAssign" class="editor-active" value="6">
                    <div class="state">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>RandomStorage1</td>
            <td class=" center"><a href="" class="editor_edit" id="6">Edit</a> <a href="" class="editor_remove" id="6">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="7" role="row" class="even">
            <td class="dt-body-center sorting_1">
                <div class="pretty p-default">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedTagsToAssign" class="editor-active" value="7">
                    <div class="state">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Storage3</td>
            <td class=" center"><a href="" class="editor_edit" id="7">Edit</a> <a href="" class="editor_remove" id="7">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="8" role="row" class="odd">
            <td class="dt-body-center sorting_1">
                <div class="pretty p-default">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedTagsToAssign" class="editor-active" value="8">
                    <div class="state">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>RandomStorage2</td>
            <td class=" center"><a href="" class="editor_edit" id="8">Edit</a> <a href="" class="editor_remove" id="8">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="9" role="row" class="even">
            <td class="dt-body-center sorting_1">
                <div class="pretty p-default">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedTagsToAssign" class="editor-active" value="9">
                    <div class="state">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Storage4</td>
            <td class=" center"><a href="" class="editor_edit" id="9">Edit</a> <a href="" class="editor_remove" id="9">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="10" role="row" class="odd">
            <td class="dt-body-center sorting_1">
                <div class="pretty p-default">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedTagsToAssign" class="editor-active" value="10">
                    <div class="state">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Storage5</td>
            <td class=" center"><a href="" class="editor_edit" id="10">Edit</a> <a href="" class="editor_remove" id="10">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="11" role="row" class="even">
            <td class="dt-body-center sorting_1">
                <div class="pretty p-default">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedTagsToAssign" class="editor-active" value="11">
                    <div class="state">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Storage6</td>
            <td class=" center"><a href="" class="editor_edit" id="11">Edit</a> <a href="" class="editor_remove" id="11">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="12" role="row" class="odd">
            <td class="dt-body-center sorting_1">
                <div class="pretty p-default">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedTagsToAssign" class="editor-active" value="12">
                    <div class="state">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Storage7</td>
            <td class=" center"><a href="" class="editor_edit" id="12">Edit</a> <a href="" class="editor_remove" id="12">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="13" role="row" class="even">
            <td class="dt-body-center sorting_1">
                <div class="pretty p-default">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedTagsToAssign" class="editor-active" value="13">
                    <div class="state">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Storage8</td>
            <td class=" center"><a href="" class="editor_edit" id="13">Edit</a> <a href="" class="editor_remove" id="13">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="14" role="row" class="odd">
            <td class="dt-body-center sorting_1">
                <div class="pretty p-default">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedTagsToAssign" class="editor-active" value="14">
                    <div class="state">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Storage9</td>
            <td class=" center"><a href="" class="editor_edit" id="14">Edit</a> <a href="" class="editor_remove" id="14">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="15" role="row" class="even">
            <td class="dt-body-center sorting_1">
                <div class="pretty p-default">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedTagsToAssign" class="editor-active" value="15">
                    <div class="state">
                        <label></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Storage10</td>
            <td class=" center"><a href="" class="editor_edit" id="15">Edit</a> <a href="" class="editor_remove" id="15">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: This removes the scroll bar entirely ( if you view your snippet in full screen , there are no scroll bar)

Comment: There is no scroll bar in the main one as well!

Comment: If we have a look to the jsFiddle in original question , there is a scrollbar. Stackoverflow for some reason removes the scroll bar, But If I copy your answer to jsFiddle then also there are no scroll bar , Here is the jsFiddle for your code, http://jsfiddle.net/645htxs9/

Comment: I just fixed my answer it have scroll bar now.